# Two way communication between Swing GUI and Client backend

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, parameter-passing

I'm trying to send a certain string when a button is pressed in my GUI. My Client class is currently running to keep taking string commands from the command line and send them to the server where they will be processed and a response will be returned.

How can I now send the data through my GUI and move the results back to my GUI?

E.g. I have a button called "pickup" which, when clicked will send the string "PICKUP" to the server, through the Client class.

Likewise, the response from the server would be either "SUCCESS" or "FAIL" which would be printed through the Thread "serverResponse" in my Client class and this needs to somehow be sent to an arbitrary method in the playerGUI class as a parameter.

Thanks for any help, sorry for not using the conventional class/method/field naming styles!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class playerGUI {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel displayPanel;
    private JTextPane hostTextPane;
    private JTextPane portTextPane;
    private static Client newclient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playerGUI GUI = new playerGUI();
        GUI.frame.setVisible(true);
        newclient = new Client(GUI);
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public playerGUI() {
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 630);
        frame.setUndecorated(false); // REMOVES MENU BAR
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel humanGameWindow = new JPanel();
        humanGameWindow.setLayout(null);
        humanGameWindow.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        humanGameWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 630);
        humanGameWindow.setVisible(false);

        JButton pickup = new JButton("Pickup");
        pickup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //I WANT TO SEND THE STRING "PICKUP" TO WHERE THE STARS ARE IN Client.class
            }
        });
        pickup.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        pickup.setBounds(40, 555, 100, 40);

        displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setBounds(48, 89, 400, 400);
        displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        displayPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (400), (int) (400)));
        for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
            displayPanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }

        JButton Look = new JButton("Look");
        Look.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        Look.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        Look.setBounds(40, 514, 100, 40);

        humanGameWindow.add(Look);
        humanGameWindow.add(pickup);
        humanGameWindow.add(displayPanel);

        final JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
        mainMenu.setLayout(null);
        mainMenu.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        mainMenu.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 630);
        mainMenu.setVisible(true);

        JLabel mainMenuTitle = new JLabel("DUNGEON OF DOOM!!");
        mainMenuTitle.setForeground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        mainMenuTitle.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 28));
        mainMenuTitle.setBounds(50, 13, 380, 50);

        JButton mainMenuQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        mainMenuQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mainMenuQuit.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        mainMenuQuit.setBounds(220, 345, 70, 55);

        JButton playGameHuman = new JButton("Play Game Human");
        playGameHuman.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                humanGameWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        playGameHuman.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
        playGameHuman.setBounds(50, 345, 150, 55);

        mainMenu.add(mainMenuTitle);
        mainMenu.add(mainMenuQuit);
        mainMenu.add(playGameHuman);

        frame.getContentPane().add(humanGameWindow);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainMenu);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This is the Client class, the thread is where I want to send the response to the GUI class to process and display a specific output. The asterisks is where I want to send the text from button presses in the GUI class (there is other buttons I have deleted the code for easier reading!).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client{
    public Client(playerGUI GUI){   
        try{
            final Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",4444);
            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

            final Thread serverResponse = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    System.out.println("DUNGEON OF DOOM HAS STARTED");
                    if(sock != null){
                        if(in != null){
                            try{
                                String response;
                                while((response = in.readLine()) != null){
                                    //I WANT TO SEND "response" TO THE GUI CLASS
                                    System.out.println(response);
                                }
                            }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
                                System.err.println("Unknown host1: " + uhe);
                            }catch(IOException ioe){
                                System.err.println("IOException1: " + ioe);
                            }catch(NullPointerException npe){
                                System.err.println("Null Pointer1: " + npe);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            serverResponse.start();
            if(sock != null){
                if(out != null){
                    try{
                        while(true){
                            String sending = *************************
                            //String sending = inputLine.readLine(); 
                            out.println(sending);
                            if(sending.equals("QUIT")) break;
                        }
                    }catch(UnknownHostException uhe2){
                        System.err.println("Unknown host2: " + uhe2);
                    }catch(IOException ioe2){
                        System.err.println("IOException2: " + ioe2);
                    }catch(NullPointerException npe2){
                        System.err.println("Null Pointer2: " + npe2);
                    }
                }
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            sock.close();
        }catch(UnknownHostException uhe3){
            System.err.println("Unknown host3: " + uhe3);
        }catch(IOException ioe3){
            System.err.println("IOException3: " + ioe3);
        }catch(NullPointerException npe3){
            System.err.println("Null Pointer3: " + npe3);
        }   
    }
}
```